# AJAX chat - Personal alerts for users (commands)

Tags: php, oop

So I have a ajax chat i've been programming,
and A commands system for it.

Basically, I want the system to give a user an alert if he doesn't use any command, and only posting a slash ( ' / ' ), and only be viewed able by the user that posted it.

But I am not to sure how to make it work.
This is my load messages method, in the chat:

```
    public function loadMessages($username)
    {
        $this->fetch = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY date, time ASC LIMIT 30");
        $this->fetch->execute();

        while ($row = $this->fetch->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            if ($row['isAlert'] == '1')
            {
                echo '<b>'.$row['date'].', '.$row['time'].' ['.$row['username'].']: </b><font color="red">'.$row['message'].'</font> <br />';
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<b>'.$row['date'].', '.$row['time'].' ['.$row['username'].']: </b>'.$row['message'].' <br />';
            }
        }
    }
```

You can see the first `if statement` in the while loop, sees if the message was a global alert, if yes, paint it to red.

**But how can I make a message that will only be viewed able to the alerted user?**

*Any ideas?*

Comment: Does your chat system have the concept of *recipient*? That is, does your database schema make it possible to represent a message specifically to a given user, or is it assumed that every message goes to every user? If you want to be able to do unicast messaging (whether from the system, for error messages, or for private messaging from user to user), you'll need some way to specify to whom a message should go, and your data model is the best place to do that. (In the case of a MySQL database, for example, you could have a `recipient` column containing a username or ID, or NULL for broadcast.)

Comment: First of all, `<font color=red>`? really? SEcond, this should probably be done on the client side (i.e. checking of the input is a command, checking if it's valid, etc). That doesn't excuse you from checking on the server as well though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a hidden `div` on the page, then use JavaScript to check if the command is valid, if not display the `div`.

For example:

```
 <div id="invalidChatCommand" style="display:none">
       <p>
          The command you entered is invalid.
       </p>
 <div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var chatCommand = document.getElementById("command").value;
    if (chatCommand.length == 1 && chatCommand.substring(0, 1) == "/") { 
       // invalid input detected, show the div
       var invalidCommand = document.getElementById("invalidChatCommand");
       invalidCommand.style.display = "block";
    } else {
       // Send command to the server
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thing is, I need it to display inside the chat, and be ordered by date, and time.

Comment: @JonyKale - rather than using a new div, append to the existing one